# Rails 3: How do I work with methods on a related object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, has-many-through

I'm updating a site with Rails 3.1 and adding some features. This application tracks tests for a collection of sites. Originally I was storing the grade for each test as a column in the Tests table but now I have created a new model called Reviews to keep a history of grades and comments assigned each test. The models look like this:

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tests
  has_many :reviews, :through => :tests

class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  belongs_to :site

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test
  has_one :user
```

Previously I could do something like this in the Site model to get some reporting data on grades:

```
def total_a_grades
  tests.count(:conditions => "reviewer_grade = 4 and review_status = 3")
end
```

Since the grades are now out of the Test model I created this method to access the most recent grade for each test:

```
def last_grade
  return reviews.find(:last).grade
end
```

This works fine for displaying the most recent grade in the test view, but how can I use it at the site level? Since the value is now in a method that's not stored in the database, I don't know how to work with it and can't find anything related to this at the major online tutorial/screencast sites.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: In the test-happy world that is Ruby, a class called **Test** is asking for trouble. I couldn't even create a Test in the Rails console. https://gist.github.com/1431777

Comment: You didn't say anything about User, but I suspect Review `belongs_to :user` instead of `has_one :user`. This article helped me a lot: [Has_One versus Belongs_To](http://duanesbrain.blogspot.com/2006/05/ruby-on-rails-hasone-versus-belongsto.html)

Answer (score 0):

The **joins** method allows access to the **has_many :through** association's attributes. Or start with the desired association, and the required joins are included for you.

```
  tests.joins(:reviews).where("reviews.grade = 5").count

  reviews.where("grade = 5").count
```

sources:

- *Active Record Query Interface* at [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/), section 11 Joining Tables
- Railscasts 181: [Include vs. Joins](http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins). Some of the methods described have changed; check out [Railscasts 202](http://railscasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3).
- Railscasts 215: [Advanced Queries in Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3). Includes some examples of associations and joins.

Comment: Methods are a lot more flexible, but for a simple case, you can add conditions to has_many: `has_many :a_grades, :through => :tests, :source => :reviews, :conditions => {:grade => 5}`